# How to remove before dot in appendices in ieee access template?

Tags: appendices, ieeetran, appendix, ieee-style, ieeeaccess

I like to remove the dot that appeared in the PDF using the IEEE Access template (on page 5 in the PDF, before the text, "Appendixes, if needed, appear before the acknowledg-
ment." Could someone help me, to do it. Below code has been copied from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-access-latex-template/cdxrhtbjgszv

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}
\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE},
\uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}, and Third C. Author,
Jr}.\authorrefmark{3},
\IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}}
\address[1]{National Institute of Standards and 
Technology, Boulder, CO 80305 USA (e-mail: author@boulder.nist.gov)}
\address[2]{Department of Physics, Colorado State University, Fort Collins, 
CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu)}
\address[3]{Electrical Engineering Department, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 
80309 USA}
\tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support 
information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
Commerce under Grant BS123456.''}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author: First A. Author (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Enter key words or phrases in alphabetical 
order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, send a blank 
e-mail to keywords@ieee.org or visit \underline
{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are 
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the 
electronic file, trans\_jour.tex, from the IEEE Web site at \underline
{http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/}\break\underline{use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-}\break\underline{templates/} so you can use it to prepare your manuscript. If 
you would prefer to use LaTeX, download IEEE's LaTeX style and sample files 
from the same Web page. You can also explore using the Overleaf editor at 
\underline
{https://www.overleaf.com/blog/278-how-to-use-overleaf-}\break\underline{with-ieee-collabratec-your-quick-guide-to-getting-started}\break\underline{\#.xsVp6tpPkrKM9}

If your paper is intended for a conference, please contact your conference 
editor concerning acceptable word processor formats for your particular 
conference. 

IEEE will do the final formatting of your paper. If your paper is intended 
for a conference, please observe the conference page limits. 

\subsection{Abbreviations and Acronyms}
Define abbreviations and acronyms the first time they are used in the text, 
even after they have already been defined in the abstract. Abbreviations 
such as IEEE, SI, ac, and dc do not have to be defined. Abbreviations that 
incorporate periods should not have spaces: write ``C.N.R.S.,'' not ``C. N. 
R. S.'' Do not use abbreviations in the title unless they are unavoidable 
(for example, ``IEEE'' in the title of this article).

\subsection{Other Recommendations}
Use one space after periods and colons. Hyphenate complex modifiers: 
``zero-field-cooled magnetization.'' Avoid dangling participles, such as, 
``Using \eqref{eq}, the potential was calculated.'' [It is not clear who or what 
used \eqref{eq}.] Write instead, ``The potential was calculated by using \eqref{eq},'' or 
``Using \eqref{eq}, we calculated the potential.''

Use a zero before decimal points: ``0.25,'' not ``.25.'' Use 
``cm$^{3}$,'' not ``cc.'' Indicate sample dimensions as ``0.1 cm 
$\times $ 0.2 cm,'' not ``0.1 $\times $ 0.2 cm$^{2}$.'' The 
abbreviation for ``seconds'' is ``s,'' not ``sec.'' Use 
``Wb/m$^{2}$'' or ``webers per square meter,'' not 
``webers/m$^{2}$.'' When expressing a range of values, write ``7 to 
9'' or ``7--9,'' not ``7$\sim $9.''

A parenthetical statement at the end of a sentence is punctuated outside of 
the closing parenthesis (like this). (A parenthetical sentence is punctuated 
within the parentheses.) In American English, periods and commas are within 
quotation marks, like ``this period.'' Other punctuation is ``outside''! 
Avoid contractions; for example, write ``do not'' instead of ``don't.'' The 
serial comma is preferred: ``A, B, and C'' instead of ``A, B and C.''

If you wish, you may write in the first person singular or plural and use 
the active voice (``I observed that $\ldots$'' or ``We observed that $\ldots$'' 
instead of ``It was observed that $\ldots$''). Remember to check spelling. If 
your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking 
colleague to carefully proofread your paper.

Try not to use too many typefaces in the same article. You're writing
scholarly papers, not ransom notes. Also please remember that MathJax
can't handle really weird typefaces.

\subsection{Equations}
Number equations consecutively with equation numbers in parentheses flush 
with the right margin, as in \eqref{eq}. To make your equations more 
compact, you may use the solidus (~/~), the exp function, or appropriate 
exponents. Use parentheses to avoid ambiguities in denominators. Punctuate 
equations when they are part of a sentence, as in
\begin{equation}E=mc^2.\label{eq}\end{equation}

Be sure that the symbols in your equation have been defined before the 
equation appears or immediately following. Italicize symbols ($T$ might refer 
to temperature, but T is the unit tesla). Refer to ``\eqref{eq},'' not ``Eq. \eqref{eq}'' 
or ``equation \eqref{eq},'' except at the beginning of a sentence: ``Equation \eqref{eq} 
is $\ldots$ .''

\subsection{\LaTeX-Specific Advice}

Please use ``soft'' (e.g., \verb|\eqref{Eq}|) cross references instead
of ``hard'' references (e.g., \verb|(1)|). That will make it possible
to combine sections, add equations, or change the order of figures or
citations without having to go through the file line by line.

Please don't use the \verb|{eqnarray}| equation environment. Use
\verb|{align}| or \verb|{IEEEeqnarray}| instead. The \verb|{eqnarray}|
environment leaves unsightly spaces around relation symbols.

Please note that the \verb|{subequations}| environment in {\LaTeX}
will increment the main equation counter even when there are no
equation numbers displayed. If you forget that, you might write an
article in which the equation numbers skip from (17) to (20), causing
the copy editors to wonder if you've discovered a new method of
counting.

{\BibTeX} does not work by magic. It doesn't get the bibliographic
data from thin air but from .bib files. If you use {\BibTeX} to produce a
bibliography you must send the .bib files. 

{\LaTeX} can't read your mind. If you assign the same label to a
subsubsection and a table, you might find that Table I has been cross
referenced as Table IV-B3. 

{\LaTeX} does not have precognitive abilities. If you put a
\verb|\label| command before the command that updates the counter it's
supposed to be using, the label will pick up the last counter to be
cross referenced instead. In particular, a \verb|\label| command
should not go before the caption of a figure or a table.

Do not use \verb|\nonumber| inside the \verb|{array}| environment. It
will not stop equation numbers inside \verb|{array}| (there won't be
any anyway) and it might stop a wanted equation number in the
surrounding equation.

\section{Units}
Use either SI (MKS) or CGS as primary units. (SI units are strongly 
encouraged.) English units may be used as secondary units (in parentheses). 
This applies to papers in data storage. For example, write ``15 
Gb/cm$^{2}$ (100 Gb/in$^{2})$.'' An exception is when 
English units are used as identifiers in trade, such as ``3\textonehalf-in 
disk drive.'' Avoid combining SI and CGS units, such as current in amperes 
and magnetic field in oersteds. This often leads to confusion because 
equations do not balance dimensionally. If you must use mixed units, clearly 
state the units for each quantity in an equation.

The SI unit for magnetic field strength $H$ is A/m. However, if you wish to use 
units of T, either refer to magnetic flux density $B$ or magnetic field 
strength symbolized as $\mu _{0}H$. Use the center dot to separate 
compound units, e.g., ``A$\cdot $m$^{2}$.''

\section{Some Common Mistakes}
The word ``data'' is plural, not singular. The subscript for the 
permeability of vacuum $\mu _{0}$ is zero, not a lowercase letter 
``o.'' The term for residual magnetization is ``remanence''; the adjective 
is ``remanent''; do not write ``remnance'' or ``remnant.'' Use the word 
``micrometer'' instead of ``micron.'' A graph within a graph is an 
``inset,'' not an ``insert.'' The word ``alternatively'' is preferred to the 
word ``alternately'' (unless you really mean something that alternates). Use 
the word ``whereas'' instead of ``while'' (unless you are referring to 
simultaneous events). Do not use the word ``essentially'' to mean 
``approximately'' or ``effectively.'' Do not use the word ``issue'' as a 
euphemism for ``problem.'' When compositions are not specified, separate 
chemical symbols by en-dashes; for example, ``NiMn'' indicates the 
intermetallic compound Ni$_{0.5}$Mn$_{0.5}$ whereas 
``Ni--Mn'' indicates an alloy of some composition 
Ni$_{x}$Mn$_{1-x}$.

\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}

Be aware of the different meanings of the homophones ``affect'' (usually a 
verb) and ``effect'' (usually a noun), ``complement'' and ``compliment,'' 
``discreet'' and ``discrete,'' ``principal'' (e.g., ``principal 
investigator'') and ``principle'' (e.g., ``principle of measurement''). Do 
not confuse ``imply'' and ``infer.'' 

Prefixes such as ``non,'' ``sub,'' ``micro,'' ``multi,'' and ``ultra'' are 
not independent words; they should be joined to the words they modify, 
usually without a hyphen. There is no period after the ``et'' in the Latin 
abbreviation ``\emph{et al.}'' (it is also italicized). The abbreviation ``i.e.,'' means 
``that is,'' and the abbreviation ``e.g.,'' means ``for example'' (these 
abbreviations are not italicized).

A general IEEE styleguide is available at \underline{http://www.ieee.org/}\break\underline{authortools}.

\section{Guidelines for Graphics Preparation and Submission}
\label{sec:guidelines}

\subsection{Types of Graphics}
The following list outlines the different types of graphics published in 
IEEE journals. They are categorized based on their construction, and use of 
color/shades of gray:

\subsubsection{Color/Grayscale figures}
{Figures that are meant to appear in color, or shades of black/gray. Such 
figures may include photographs, illustrations, multicolor graphs, and 
flowcharts.}

\subsubsection{Line Art figures}
{Figures that are composed of only black lines and shapes. These figures 
should have no shades or half-tones of gray, only black and white.}

\subsubsection{Author photos}
{Head and shoulders shots of authors that appear at the end of our papers. }

\subsubsection{Tables}
{Data charts which are typically black and white, but sometimes include 
color.}

\begin{table}
\caption{Units for Magnetic Properties}
\label{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{25pt}|p{75pt}|p{115pt}|}
\hline
Symbol& 
Quantity& 
Conversion from Gaussian and \par CGS EMU to SI $^{\mathrm{a}}$ \\
\hline
$\Phi $& 
magnetic flux& 
1 Mx $\to  10^{-8}$ Wb $= 10^{-8}$ V$\cdot $s \\
$B$& 
magnetic flux density, \par magnetic induction& 
1 G $\to  10^{-4}$ T $= 10^{-4}$ Wb/m$^{2}$ \\
$H$& 
magnetic field strength& 
1 Oe $\to  10^{3}/(4\pi )$ A/m \\
$m$& 
magnetic moment& 
1 erg/G $=$ 1 emu \par $\to 10^{-3}$ A$\cdot $m$^{2} = 10^{-3}$ J/T \\
$M$& 
magnetization& 
1 erg/(G$\cdot $cm$^{3}) =$ 1 emu/cm$^{3}$ \par $\to 10^{3}$ A/m \\
4$\pi M$& 
magnetization& 
1 G $\to  10^{3}/(4\pi )$ A/m \\
$\sigma $& 
specific magnetization& 
1 erg/(G$\cdot $g) $=$ 1 emu/g $\to $ 1 A$\cdot $m$^{2}$/kg \\
$j$& 
magnetic dipole \par moment& 
1 erg/G $=$ 1 emu \par $\to 4\pi \times  10^{-10}$ Wb$\cdot $m \\
$J$& 
magnetic polarization& 
1 erg/(G$\cdot $cm$^{3}) =$ 1 emu/cm$^{3}$ \par $\to 4\pi \times  10^{-4}$ T \\
$\chi , \kappa $& 
susceptibility& 
1 $\to  4\pi $ \\
$\chi_{\rho }$& 
mass susceptibility& 
1 cm$^{3}$/g $\to  4\pi \times  10^{-3}$ m$^{3}$/kg \\
$\mu $& 
permeability& 
1 $\to  4\pi \times  10^{-7}$ H/m \par $= 4\pi \times  10^{-7}$ Wb/(A$\cdot $m) \\
$\mu_{r}$& 
relative permeability& 
$\mu \to \mu_{r}$ \\
$w, W$& 
energy density& 
1 erg/cm$^{3} \to  10^{-1}$ J/m$^{3}$ \\
$N, D$& 
demagnetizing factor& 
1 $\to  1/(4\pi )$ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{p{251pt}}{Vertical lines are optional in tables. Statements that serve as captions for 
the entire table do not need footnote letters. }\\
\multicolumn{3}{p{251pt}}{$^{\mathrm{a}}$Gaussian units are the same as cg emu for magnetostatics; Mx 
$=$ maxwell, G $=$ gauss, Oe $=$ oersted; Wb $=$ weber, V $=$ volt, s $=$ 
second, T $=$ tesla, m $=$ meter, A $=$ ampere, J $=$ joule, kg $=$ 
kilogram, H $=$ henry.}
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\subsection{Multipart figures}
Figures compiled of more than one sub-figure presented side-by-side, or 
stacked. If a multipart figure is made up of multiple figure
types (one part is lineart, and another is grayscale or color) the figure 
should meet the stricter guidelines.

\subsection{File Formats For Graphics}\label{formats}
Format and save your graphics using a suitable graphics processing program 
that will allow you to create the images as PostScript (PS), Encapsulated 
PostScript (.EPS), Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF), Portable Document 
Format (.PDF), Portable Network Graphics (.PNG), or Metapost (.MPS), sizes them, and adjusts 
the resolution settings. When 
submitting your final paper, your graphics should all be submitted 
individually in one of these formats along with the manuscript.

\subsection{Sizing of Graphics}
Most charts, graphs, and tables are one column wide (3.5 inches/88 
millimeters/21 picas) or page wide (7.16 inches/181 millimeters/43 
picas). The maximum depth a graphic can be is 8.5 inches (216 millimeters/54
picas). When choosing the depth of a graphic, please allow space for a 
caption. Figures can be sized between column and page widths if the author 
chooses, however it is recommended that figures are not sized less than 
column width unless when necessary. 

There is currently one publication with column measurements that do not 
coincide with those listed above. Proceedings of the IEEE has a column 
measurement of 3.25 inches (82.5 millimeters/19.5 picas). 

The final printed size of author photographs is exactly
1 inch wide by 1.25 inches tall (25.4 millimeters$\,\times\,$31.75 millimeters/6 
picas$\,\times\,$7.5 picas). Author photos printed in editorials measure 1.59 inches 
wide by 2 inches tall (40 millimeters$\,\times\,$50 millimeters/9.5 picas$\,\times\,$12 
picas).

\subsection{Resolution }
The proper resolution of your figures will depend on the type of figure it 
is as defined in the ``Types of Figures'' section. Author photographs, 
color, and grayscale figures should be at least 300dpi. Line art, including 
tables should be a minimum of 600dpi.

\subsection{Vector Art}
In order to preserve the figures' integrity across multiple computer 
platforms, we accept files in the following formats: .EPS/.PDF/.PS. All 
fonts must be embedded or text converted to outlines in order to achieve the 
best-quality results.

\subsection{Color Space}
The term color space refers to the entire sum of colors that can be 
represented within the said medium. For our purposes, the three main color 
spaces are Grayscale, RGB (red/green/blue) and CMYK 
(cyan/magenta/yellow/black). RGB is generally used with on-screen graphics, 
whereas CMYK is used for printing purposes.

All color figures should be generated in RGB or CMYK color space. Grayscale 
images should be submitted in Grayscale color space. Line art may be 
provided in grayscale OR bitmap colorspace. Note that ``bitmap colorspace'' 
and ``bitmap file format'' are not the same thing. When bitmap color space 
is selected, .TIF/.TIFF/.PNG are the recommended file formats.

\subsection{Accepted Fonts Within Figures}
When preparing your graphics IEEE suggests that you use of one of the 
following Open Type fonts: Times New Roman, Helvetica, Arial, Cambria, and 
Symbol. If you are supplying EPS, PS, or PDF files all fonts must be 
embedded. Some fonts may only be native to your operating system; without 
the fonts embedded, parts of the graphic may be distorted or missing.

A safe option when finalizing your figures is to strip out the fonts before 
you save the files, creating ``outline'' type. This converts fonts to 
artwork what will appear uniformly on any screen.

\subsection{Using Labels Within Figures}

\subsubsection{Figure Axis labels }
Figure axis labels are often a source of confusion. Use words rather than 
symbols. As an example, write the quantity ``Magnetization,'' or 
``Magnetization M,'' not just ``M.'' Put units in parentheses. Do not label 
axes only with units. As in Fig. 1, for example, write ``Magnetization 
(A/m)'' or ``Magnetization (A$\cdot$m$^{-1}$),'' not just ``A/m.'' Do not label axes with a ratio of quantities and 
units. For example, write ``Temperature (K),'' not ``Temperature/K.'' 

Multipliers can be especially confusing. Write ``Magnetization (kA/m)'' or 
``Magnetization (10$^{3}$ A/m).'' Do not write ``Magnetization 
(A/m)$\,\times\,$1000'' because the reader would not know whether the top 
axis label in Fig. 1 meant 16000 A/m or 0.016 A/m. Figure labels should be 
legible, approximately 8 to 10 point type.

\subsubsection{Subfigure Labels in Multipart Figures and Tables}
Multipart figures should be combined and labeled before final submission. 
Labels should appear centered below each subfigure in 8 point Times New 
Roman font in the format of (a) (b) (c). 

\subsection{File Naming}
Figures (line artwork or photographs) should be named starting with the 
first 5 letters of the author's last name. The next characters in the 
filename should be the number that represents the sequential 
location of this image in your article. For example, in author 
``Anderson's'' paper, the first three figures would be named ander1.tif, 
ander2.tif, and ander3.ps.

Tables should contain only the body of the table (not the caption) and 
should be named similarly to figures, except that `.t' is inserted 
in-between the author's name and the table number. For example, author 
Anderson's first three tables would be named ander.t1.tif, ander.t2.ps, 
ander.t3.eps.

Author photographs should be named using the first five characters of the 
pictured author's last name. For example, four author photographs for a 
paper may be named: oppen.ps, moshc.tif, chen.eps, and duran.pdf.

If two authors or more have the same last name, their first initial(s) can 
be substituted for the fifth, fourth, third$\ldots$ letters of their surname 
until the degree where there is differentiation. For example, two authors 
Michael and Monica Oppenheimer's photos would be named oppmi.tif, and 
oppmo.eps.

\subsection{Referencing a Figure or Table Within Your Paper}
When referencing your figures and tables within your paper, use the 
abbreviation ``Fig.'' even at the beginning of a sentence. Do not abbreviate 
``Table.'' Tables should be numbered with Roman Numerals.

\subsection{Checking Your Figures: The IEEE Graphics Analyzer}
The IEEE Graphics Analyzer enables authors to pre-screen their graphics for 
compliance with IEEE Access standards before submission. 
The online tool, located at
\underline{http://graphicsqc.ieee.org/}, allows authors to 
upload their graphics in order to check that each file is the correct file 
format, resolution, size and colorspace; that no fonts are missing or 
corrupt; that figures are not compiled in layers or have transparency, and 
that they are named according to the IEEE Access naming 
convention. At the end of this automated process, authors are provided with 
a detailed report on each graphic within the web applet, as well as by 
email.

For more information on using the Graphics Analyzer or any other graphics 
related topic, contact the IEEE Graphics Help Desk by e-mail at 
graphics@ieee.org.

\subsection{Submitting Your Graphics}
\lipsum[1-1]

\subsection{Color Processing/Printing in IEEE Journals}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Conclusion}
A conclusion section is not required. Although a conclusion may review the 
main points of the paper, do not replicate the abstract as the conclusion. A 
conclusion might elaborate on the importance of the work or suggest 
applications and extensions. 

\appendices

Appendixes, if needed, appear before the acknowledgment.

\section*{Acknowledgment}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section*{References and Footnotes}

\subsection{References}

\lipsum[1-1]

\subsection{Footnotes}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{Submitting Your Paper for Review}

\lipsum[1-1]

\subsection{Copyright Form}
\lipsum[1-1]

\section{IEEE Publishing Policy}
The general IEEE policy requires that authors should only submit original 
work that has neither appeared elsewhere for publication, nor is under 
review for another refereed publication. The submitting author must disclose 
all prior publication(s) and current submissions when submitting a 
manuscript. Do not publish ``preliminary'' data or results. The submitting 
author is responsible for obtaining agreement of all coauthors and any 
consent required from employers or sponsors before submitting an article. 
The IEEE Access Department strongly discourages courtesy 
authorship; it is the obligation of the authors to cite only relevant prior 
work.

The IEEE Access Department does not publish conference 
records or proceedings, but can publish articles related to conferences that 
have undergone rigorous peer review. Minimally, two reviews are required for 
every article submitted for peer review.

\section{Publication Principles}
The two types of contents of that are published are; 1) peer-reviewed and 2) 
archival. The Access Department publishes scholarly 
articles of archival value as well as tutorial expositions and critical 
reviews of classical subjects and topics of current interest. 

Authors should consider the following points:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Technical papers submitted for publication must advance the state of knowledge and must cite relevant prior work. 
\item The length of a submitted paper should be commensurate with the importance, or appropriate to the complexity, of the work. For example, an obvious extension of previously published work might not be appropriate for publication or might be adequately treated in just a few pages.
\item Authors must convince both peer reviewers and the editors of the scientific and technical merit of a paper; the standards of proof are higher when extraordinary or unexpected results are reported. 

\item \emph{Article number in~reference examples:}\\
See \cite{b32,b33}.

\item \emph{Example when using et al.:}\\
See \cite{b34}.

\end{itemize}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\bibitem{b1} G. O. Young, ``Synthetic structure of industrial plastics,'' in \emph{Plastics,} 2\textsuperscript{nd} ed., vol. 3, J. Peters, Ed. New York, NY, USA: McGraw-Hill, 1964, pp. 15--64.

\bibitem{b2} W.-K. Chen, \emph{Linear Networks and Systems.} Belmont, CA, USA: Wadsworth, 1993, pp. 123--135.

\bibitem{b3} J. U. Duncombe, ``Infrared navigation---Part I: An assessment of feasibility,'' \emph{IEEE Trans. Electron Devices}, vol. ED-11, no. 1, pp. 34--39, Jan. 1959, 10.1109/TED.2016.2628402.

\bibitem{b4} E. P. Wigner, ``Theory of traveling-wave optical laser,'' \emph{Phys. Rev}., vol. 134, pp. A635--A646, Dec. 1965.

\end{IEEEbiography}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot in Line 196 of `ieeeaccess.cls` should do.

```
\def\thesectiondis{APPENDIX \Alph{section}}.%
```

into

```
\def\thesectiondis{APPENDIX \Alph{section}}%
```

I personally find the IEEE Access template not quite well written, and there are numerous known issues, for example working with TikZ.